# htaccess mod_rewrite with 2.4 apache not working as expected

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here is all my htaccess code

```
   #Options -MultiViews

   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#
#  This Conditions is for admin
#

   RewriteRule   ^admin/$                     admin/index.php                   [L]
   RewriteRule   ^admin/(index|login|process|action|logout|ajax|controller).php  admin/$1.php?             [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule   ^admin/(.*).php             admin/controller.php?plugin=$1                    [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule   ^admin/(.*)                  admin/router.php?t=$1                             [QSA,L]

#
#  This Conditions is for Themes
#

   RewriteRule   ^theme/(.*)    view/themes/$1                  [QSA,L]

   RewriteRule   ^admin_theme/(.*) view/admins/$1               [QSA,L]

#
#  This Conditions is for App
#
   RewriteRule   ^(.*).(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|woff|ttf|otf|mp3|mp4|ogg)$       app/$1.$2      [QSA,L]

   RewriteRule   (post_comment|feed|login|action|reset|index).php       app/$1.php            [QSA,L]

   RewriteRule   ^$             app/index.php                   [L]

   RewriteRule   ^(.*)?         app/router.php?regex=$1              [QSA,L]

   RewriteRule   (.*)           app/$1                          [QSA,L]
```

Every thing working fine but this condition

`RewriteRule ^admin/(.*).php  admin/controller.php?plugin=$1     [QSA,L]`

redirect to this link
**/app/router.php?regex=site.com/admin/users.php**

but i should be this

**site.com/admin/controller.php?plugin=users&**

I'm working on localhost **xampp* no problems found

but after uploading to server apache 2.4  problem apper

i'm using this website to check my htaccess codes

**http://htaccess.mwl.be/**

Whats is the problem here and how this should work with apache 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Escape the special character `.` with back-slash `\.`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alalmea.art4muslim.net
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)\.php  /admin/controller.php?plugin=$1     [QSA,L]
```

---

For `PCRE`, and most other so-called Perl-compatible flavors, escape these outside character classes:

```
.^$*+?()[{\|
```

Comment: not working , still send me to `/app/router.php?regex=site.com/admin/users.php`

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)\.php  /admin/controller.php?plugin=$1     [QSA,L]`

Comment: i can't see any diffrent 
**note: i'm working on subdomain**

Comment: There's a difference `/`. Where did you mention **subdomain** before ?

Comment: i'm working here
http://alalmea.art4muslim.net/
and admin  here
http://alalmea.art4muslim.net/admin/
admin
admin
the problem is here
http://alalmea.art4muslim.net/admin/posts.php
should be 
http://alalmea.art4muslim.net/admin/controller.php?plugin=posts